# Solutions to $a+b+c=12$, $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}_0$

Tags: combinatorics, diophantine-equations

Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}_0$. If $a+b+c=12$, how many solutions $(a,b,c)$ satisfy the equation?

Is the answer:

> $729$

Comment: Hint: how many $a,b$ are there that satisfy $a+b=n$ for a given $n$?

Comment: I have to ask, is $0\in\Bbb{N}$ for you? It's not really agreed upon unanimously, I've seen $\Bbb{N} = \{0,1,\ldots\}$ and $\Bbb{N} = \{1,2,\ldots\}$. Obviously, the choice changes the answer.

Comment: Perhaps we need to know the basics of the problem.  Is $0$ in $\mathbb N$?  Are $(2,3,7)$ and $(3,2,7)$ the same solution?

Comment: @Stahl, I was going to ask the same as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#History_of_natural_numbers_and_the_status_of_zero

Comment: are (a,b,c) ordered triples

Comment: By ordered triple do you mean (12,0,0) is considered the same as (0,12,0)? If so, no.

Comment: Ordered triple means (12,0,0) is *not* the same as (0,12,0), because order matters.

Comment: If you got your answer, please mark the question as marked.

Answer (score 14):

Hint: Imagine that you put $12$ coins on a table, side by side on a horizontal line with some spacing between them. You have $2$ pencils each of which you can put between any two of the coins. The $2$ pencils separate these $12$ coins to three groups. These three groups represent the numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$. We now count..

Comment: This method commonly goes by the name [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: @Lord_Farin Haha, didn't know that, thanks for the info.

Comment: We seriously count till we arrive at $14 \choose 2$?

Comment: @Inceptio I am at 76...

Comment: ... conversation of two Lords :) ...

Answer (score 4):

Force $a=0$, then, $b+c=12$ has $13$ solutions. Force $a=1$, then, $b+c=11$ has $12$ solutions. In general forcing $a=n$ yields $13-n$ solutions. Since $a$ can run from $0$ to $12$, the total number of solutions is $$\sum_{n=0}^{12}(13-n)=91$$ 
In general the equation $a+b+c=m$ has $\binom{m+2}{2}$ solutions in $\mathbb{N}_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Use generating functions.  The generating function for $\mathbb{N}_0$ is

$$1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n + \cdots = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

That is, that the number of ways to write an integer $n$ as an integer is $1$, and the series whose coefficient of $x^n$ is that value is $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

The generating function of the sum of three integers is then that function raised to the third power:

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2} x^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

If N<sub>0</sub> refers to natural numbers {1,2,....}, then the answer is 54 
else if it refers to whole number {0,1,2,...}, then the answer is 87 if I am not wrong.